# SQL - Dúvida na query

Tags: sql

Galera estou com uma dúvida tremenda, tenho essas 3 colunas necessito apenas que traga o menor registro caso a data esteja entre o between.
Exemplo: Caso coloque data 23/12/2015 a 01/01/2016 não é para trazer registro pois o menor registro tem data 18/12/2015.

[image: Tabela]

Segue minha query mas está errada, pois está trazendo o menor registro mesmo que a data não seja 18/12/2015.

```
select min(b.reg) Menor_Reg, b.dt_ate, b.pront
from recadate b
inner join tbcbopro c on b.crm=c.cod
inner join tbprofis d on c.id_tbprofis=d.id
inner join tbcbosus e on e.id=c.id_tbcbosus
inner join repacagd f on f.crm=b.crm
inner join tbconven g on b.conv=g.cod
where b.dt_ate between '23.12.2015' and '01.01.2016'
and b.pront=116312
group by b.pront, dt_ate
```

[image: Resultado da query]

Queria que trouxesse o menor registro apenas se a data fosse por exemplo 18/12/2015.

Obrigado desde, já, qualquer ajuda é bem vinda...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mas a data que se quer 18/12/2015 não está entre o intervalo 23.12.2015 e 01.01.2016, parece quer trazer a menor apenas se a menor geral estiver no intervalo pedido , o quer fazer quando não estiver trazer nulo ?

Tente algo assim todavia

```
select min(b.reg) Menor_geral, 
       min(case when b.dt_ate between '23.12.2015' and '01.01.2016' then b.reg else null end) menor_intervalo,
b.dt_ate, b.pront
from recadate b
inner join tbcbopro c on b.crm=c.cod
inner join tbprofis d on c.id_tbprofis=d.id
inner join tbcbosus e on e.id=c.id_tbcbosus
inner join repacagd f on f.crm=b.crm
inner join tbconven g on b.conv=g.cod
where b.pront=116312
group by b.pront, dt_ate
```

Comment: Cara parabéns, funcionou perfeitamente não imaginava que um simples caso conseguiria resolver isso.. Obrigado mesmo !

Comment: Motta como seria caso eu quisesse trazer apenas linhas onde menor_intervalo seja <> null?

Comment: having min(case when b.dt_ate between '23.12.2015' and '01.01.2016' then b.reg else null end) is null